# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'date' in thymeleaf form

Tags: spring, kotlin, thymeleaf, java-time

```
<form th:action="@{/hi}"  th:object="${datum}" method="post">
    <p>date : <input type="date" th:field="*{date}"/> </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```

Controller for form above

```
@PostMapping("/hi")
fun testum(@ModelAttribute datum: Datum) {
    println(datum)
}
```

simple pojo class

```
class Datum(
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        var date: LocalDate? = null
)
```

I am trying to send date in form but get this exception:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'datum' on field 'date': rejected value [2018-06-20]; codes [typeMismatch.datum.date,typeMismatch.date,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [datum.date,date]; arguments []; default message [date]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2018-06-20'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2018-06-20]]
```

But if I change type from LocalDate to String it works fine. I want to map date that is in form to date property of Datum class. can anyone help me with that? any links? thanks.

This link did not help me [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079923/localdate-in-form)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693971/input-type-date-thymeleaf

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but I'm leaving an answer just for future readers.
This is not an issue with thymeleaf, and more of an issue of `@DateTimeFormat` binding.
The example in the question above will work if the `Datum` class is changed like so:

#### Solution 1.

```
class Datum {
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    var date: LocalDate? = null
}
```

note that the `date` field has been moved from declaring in the primary constructor into the class body.
(notice the change from `Datum (...)` to `Datum {...}`)

#### Solution 2.

```
class Datum (
   @field:DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") var date: LocalDate? = null
)
```

if you need to have it declared inside constructor due to having it as `data class` or other reasons, you have to annotate using [use-site targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets).
**HOWEVER**, beware that Solution 2 may not always work. I cannot reproduce in a sample project - but in a real-life project, there was an issue where `@field:DateTimeFormat` didn't correctly bind the request parameter string to the `Date` object. It sometimes worked and sometimes didn't, making it very tricky to debug.
When it didn't work, it spewed out errors like `Validation failed for object='Datum'. Error count: 1`, while reverting to Solution 1 instead always worked. Every time we compiled again, Solution 2 sometimes worked and randomly broke without any code changes.
We've resorted to strictly putting `@DateTimeFormat` annotated fields down to the class body declaration to insure it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just created your example using this as controller:

```
@Controller
public class StackOverflow {

@GetMapping("/stack")
public String template(Model m) {
    m.addAttribute("datum", new Datanum());
    return "stackoverflow.html";
}

@PostMapping("/stack2")
public String testum(@ModelAttribute Datanum user) {
    System.out.println(user.getDate());
    return null;
}
}
```

this as view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form th:action="@{/stack2}"  th:object="${datum}" method="post">
            <p>date : <input type="date" th:field="*{date}"/> </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this as Bean

```
   import java.time.LocalDate;

   import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

   public class Datanum{
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private LocalDate date;

        public LocalDate getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }
```

and it worked:

[image]

[image]

The difference I see is that you're using var on your Bean

```
  var date: LocalDate? = null
```

I think that is Java 10, isn't it? why don't you try to use

the bean as I did , maybe that could help you.

instead of var use LocalDate

hope this works

Comment: it is not java 10 it is kotlin. thanks. switched back to java from kotlin

Comment: class Datum (
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        var date: LocalDate
)
Problem was that I create properties in primary constructor, I do not know why but thymeleaf cannot set values in that way. it did not work with default values even  
class Datum (
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        var date: LocalDate = LocalDate.MIN
)

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is totally unrelated to the question. It doesn't use the correct language(kotlin), and all it points out is that it works in Java. The main issue in the original question is not having annotation use targets set up correctly, so this answer should probably be downvoted for less visibility to prevent future readers getting confused.

Comment: @Yussef You saved my day